# how do i update database using ADODB.Recordset?

Tags: sql, mysql, excel, vba

i am using excel to connect to a mysql database:

```
Dim dpath, atime, rtime, lcalib, aname, rname, bstate, instrument As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    ConnectDB
    With wsBooks
           rs.Open "batchinfo", oConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable


    Worksheets.Item("Report 1").Select
    dpath = Trim(Range("B2").Text)
    atime = Trim(Range("B3").Text)
    rtime = Trim(Range("B4").Text)
    lcalib = Trim(Range("B5").Text)
    aname = Trim(Range("B6").Text)
    rname = Trim(Range("B7").Text)
    bstate = Trim(Range("B8").Text)

       ' instrument = GetInstrFromXML(wbBook.FullName)

    With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("datapath") = dpath
        .Fields("analysistime") = atime
        .Fields("reporttime") = rtime
        .Fields("lastcalib") = lcalib
        .Fields("analystname") = aname
        .Fields("reportname") = rname
        .Fields("batchstate") = "bstate"
        .Fields("instrument") = "NA"
        .Update

 ' stores the new record
    End With
```

what is the next step?

how do i do an rs.execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should rs.Update() do this? Or you could call rs.Requery(), which updates and refreshed the recordset.